# How to handle i18next new type DefaultTFuncReturn?

Tags: reactjs, i18next

Yesterday, `i18next` introduced a new return type `DefaultTFuncReturn`, I am trying to upgrade this dependency with a whole bunch of errors. This is because it used to return a string, now it returns `DefaultTFuncReturn` every time I use the `useTranslation` hook. For example:

```
const { t } = useTranslation();
...
t('Test')
```

Now the return type of `t('Test')` is `DefaultTFuncReturn`, but if I use variables inside the function like `t('{{var}} something', { var })` it returns a string, so it works in that case. I couldn't find anything in the documentation explaining this new change, so I wanted to know how you are handling this since I know this package is used by a lot of people.

Comment: https://github.com/i18next/i18next/issues/1852

Comment: That was actually me haha!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and found a fix in the [official docs here](https://www.i18next.com/overview/typescript).
i18next's `t` method can now return a `null` value which needs to be prevented.
Find your i18n configuration, probably called something like `i18n.ts`.

```
// i18n.ts
import 'i18next';

// declare custom type options so the return is always a string.

declare module 'i18next' {
  interface CustomTypeOptions {
    returnNull: false
  }
}

// update the initialization so the behavior matches the type:
i18next.init({
  returnNull: false,
  // ... any other initializations here
});
```

Comment: For me just adding the new interface fixed this (it doesn't seem like I needed to update the init)

Comment: it has to be `i18next.d.ts`