# Im having issues with i18next in react 18

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, i18next

I cant use t from i18n inside a label (nor inside any html tag for that matter) and i cant figure out why, if i use it outside of tags in jsx it works fine and grabs translation from my json files.

Code example:
`<label htmlFor={"username"}>{t("Username")}</label>`

im getting the error message:
Type 'DefaultTFuncReturn' is not assignable to type 'ReactI18NextChild | Iterable'.
Type 'object' is not assignable to type 'ReactI18NextChild | Iterable'.

Has anyone had similar issue and do you know how to solve it?

Comment: https://github.com/i18next/i18next/issues/1852

Comment: thanks, hope its fixed when they merge it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I answered this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74143213/how-to-handle-i18next-new-type-defaulttfuncreturn/74808715#74808715) also but sharing here as well.

I had the same problem and found a fix in the [official docs here](https://www.i18next.com/overview/typescript). i18next's `t` method can return a `null` value but was only recently reflected in the types. The `null` return needs to be prevented. Find your i18n configuration, probably called `i18n.ts`.

```
// i18n.ts
import 'i18next';

// declare custom type options so the return is always a string.

declare module 'i18next' {
  interface CustomTypeOptions {
    returnNull: false
  }
}

// update the initialization so the behavior matches the type:
i18next.init({
  returnNull: false,
  // ... any other initializations here
});
```

Comment: the t function can return null since the beginning… but it was not reflected in the types

Answer (score 3):

I "solved" the issue by wrapping label contents in a fragment tag like this:
`<label htmlFor={"username"}><>{t("Username")}</></label>`
this works as its supposed to and doesnt throw errors but im not sure how viable this solution is and still havent figured out why exactly does it happen

Answer (score 1):

Another solution for solve this, you could add

```
t("Username") ?? "";
```

Or create a function with this comportment and call it in place of t

```
const tOverwrite = (key : string) : string => i18next.t(key) ?? "";
```